# A non-trivial solution of $y'' + xy = 0$ is monotonic in $(a,0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y$  be a non-trivial solution of $y'' + xy = 0$, where $x \in [a,b]$, $y(a) = y(b) = 0$. Show that $y$ is monotonic in $(a,0)$ if $a < 0 < b$.

I know that $y$ will have just one zero in $[a,0]$.

I don't know how can I prove the monotonicity of $y$.

Please help.

Comment: Hint: $ y''=  \frac{dy'}{dx} = \frac{dy'}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}= y' \frac{dy'}{dx}$, using this you can solve for $y'$.

Comment: @APCorreia..Uhmm..No..Didn't study how to find the solution of second order differential equations yet in my course.

Comment: @Buraian..Is there any other way?

Comment: How did you get that $y$ will have just one zero in that interval? In the closed interval there are two zeros to start off with. One piece of info which you could get tho is by using rolles theorem. There is a point $c$ w/ f'(c) =0. Edit: My bad, I see the interval is [0,a] now

Comment: I said one zero in $[a,0]$

Comment: I used this result that if $q(x) \leq 0$ in $y"+q(x)y =0$ then any non-trivial solution has atmost one zero.

Comment: Do you have the proof of that result with you? I can't see how one could prove that true without seeing the solution for $y$ directly

Comment: No..I don't have the proof. I just saw that statement somewhere in the book.

Comment: Also..In Tyn Myint-U, it has been proven without finding the solution of $y$

Comment: Could you give the exact statement of the theorem/ result you used to identify that the function had a zero in [0,a]?

Comment: I can clearly see that it has one zero viz a. It has no other zero by that statement that I already stated.

Comment: I used this result that if q(x)≤0 in y"+q(x)y=0 then any non-trivial solution has atmost one zero.

Comment: If $y$ had a change of monotonicity, then there would be a local extremum. With the equation $y''(x)=-xy(x)$, this is impossible for $x<0$, for instance at a maximum $y(x)>0$ while $y''(x)$ should be negative, which however contradicts $(-x)y(x)>0$.

Comment: $y''(x)$ should be negative? Can you explain this?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $2y'$ and integrate over $(a,c)$ for any $c \in (a,0)$, you will find
$\left[y'(x)^2 + xy(x)^2\right]^c_a = \int_a^c y(x)^2 dx \ge 0$. Rearrange the terms you will find $|y'(c)| \ge |y'(a)| > 0$.

Comment: Close to a maximum a sufficiently smooth function is concave, has negative curvature, a negative (non-positive, but zero can be easily excluded) second derivative. For a minimum mirror this on the $x$-axis.

Comment: Are you using the second derivative test that says if $f''(x_0) < 0$ then there is a local maximum at $x_0$. Are you using the converse of this? Does the converse also hold true?

Comment: Okay..Fine I got that $y''(x)$ is less than or equal to 0

Comment: y"(x) can't be 0 as if it is 0 then xy(x) = 0 but neither x nor y(x) can be 0..right?